# How do i restrict direct access of any route and throw 404 exception even routes present?

Tags: laravel, exception, routes, http-status-code-404

I want to add a restriction on direct access of any URL from the address bar. If a user enters any URL in the address bar then it should throw 404 exceptions even URL is present. Can anyone have an idea please give suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The real question is **why** would you want to prevent this. Because it will not make the website more protected by just preventing direct typing a url. Also it will prevent users that like to work this way to use this function.

Comment: OP could you please explain why you need to prevent this as we may be able to come to a better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 solutions, each with their own flaws:

**Client side routes**

https://medium.com/@fro_g/routing-in-javascript-d552ff4d2921

This way the direct pages don't have to exist on the server. Javascript will handle history state.

**Check referer**

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

This will show the previous page the user was coming from (according to the browser). This will be empty when visiting an url directly.

**Exclusively use POST pages after homepage**

As the browser is able to show POST pages when submitting forms etc. It can only show GET requests by typing an url.

In all cases the user can trick the server as if he navigated to the page in the intended way. *Which means there is no 100% sure way to disable direct access as you cannot trust the client.*

Answer (score 0):

Server Side, you can't.

Not easily anyway. For the server, a request is a request and no request header flag actually exist that tells you if the user entered the `URL` manually or not.

One thing you can work on, manually entered `URL` can only do `GET` requests.

An idea to work on would be to track the user navigation through your site/api and have a list of possible transitions.

Comment: what if i have "success" page after successfully order created. this page should be display only after order but user enter direct url from address bar to access it without  processing order?

Comment: @sandy This needs a business solution, not a coding one. You can for example check that an order has just been submitted by the user to show him a success page, or that the order related to the success page exists at all. or register somewhere (cookies, Database, Cache) that the success page for that order has already been shown or not.... a lot of solutions

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware)

If you do not want to define your own `middleware`, use a `Gate`.

```php
# A service provider. Can be app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php for example
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    // Only users 1 through 6 can view-pages. Write your own logic.
    Gate::define('view-pages', function ($user) {
        $allowed = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        return in_array($user->id, $allowed);
    });
}
```

If it gets too messy and you want to use a different file, read on Policies. It's basically the same thing as using `Controllers` in the routes files instead of using `Closures`.

You can then use the `can` middleware on your routes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-middleware

```php
# routes/web.php
// can:view-pages checks if User passes the defined Gate view-pages.
// If it doesn't, throws a 403 (Forbidden).
Route::middleware('can:view-pages')->group(function(){
    Route::get(...)
    Route::post(...)
    ...
});
// Can also be done route by route
Route::get('path/to/', 'SomeController@someAction')->middleware('can:view-pages');
```

As commented above, this throws 403s. That is because failing a Gate check in middleware (or using `$this->authorize()` inside a `Controller`) throws an `Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException`, which Laravel handles by throwing a 403.

If you want to customize this behavior, you can use the [Exception handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#the-exception-handler) 's [render](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#render-method) method to do so.

```php
# app\Exceptions\Handler.php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: this only for single page solution my question is suppose I have user/1 page now any user change the id in URL it should redirect to 404 pages. No direct URL manipulation allowed that's what I want.

Comment: OP is not asking about permission/roles. He wants to prevents a page from appearing if the user enters the url, but to appear if he redirects him there.

Comment: sounds like he wants to make his own middleware then.

Comment: but using middleware how would you identify this request comes form redirection not from directly address bar?

Comment: The request object is probably enough for that. It will get you some information, like the referrer. The headers and the referrer for example. The middleware is just to avoid duplicating too much code.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments (see: "*this only for single page solution my question is suppose I have user/1 page now any user change the id in URL it should redirect to 404 pages. No direct URL manipulation allowed that's what I want.*"), it seems like this is the issue you are trying to solve:

> User x wants to view their profile. The route to this profile is mysite.local/user/x. The 'x' represents the id of the user. If User x were to type mysite.local/user/y, they shouldn't be able to see the profile of user y, they should receive a 403 (forbidden).

(**I would suggest using the HTTP status code 403 as the page technically exists, the user is just not allowed to view it.**)

There are many ways that you can go about doing this - you don't need to necessarily focus on URL being 'typed' as you can tackle this issue in a variety of ways which may be more secure.

In your controller for the page(s) in question, you can add a check for authentication, assuming that you use Laravel Auth. So, using the scenario you gave in the comments above where you have a route for 'user/1', where the linked controller function takes in the parameter `User $user`, you can do something like this:

```
if ($user->id !== Auth::id()) {
    return abort(403, 'Forbidden'); // you can throw this as a 404 if you like
}
```

You can save this as a function, i.e. `private function checkForAuth(User $user)` and call this at the start of every function in your controller.

Now, this may change - say I am an admin and I should still be able to go and see mysite.local/user/x, as the admin has the privileges to view this - awesome, we can make a function for that too.

In your, for example, User model, you can set up a function like so:

```
public function canBeViewedBy(User $user) : bool
{

     $adminAccounts = ... // however you decide as user is an 'admin', pluck IDs

     // If you are the user, you can view your own profile
    if ($user->id == $this->user_id) {
        return true;
    }

    // If you are an admin, you can view this user
    if (in_array($this->user_id, $adminAccounts)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can then call this at the start of your controller functions instead, like so:

`if ($user->canBeViewedBy(Auth::user()) ....`

If you are in a situation where you have administrators or users with different levels that can have different viewing access, that is where middleware comes in. I would create a model & table combo for roles, and have inside your User model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

public function hasRole(Role $role)
{
    $roles = $this->roles()->where('name', $role->name)->first();

    if ($roles) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

You can then call this in some middleware, e.g. Role.php which you instantiate with a Role `$role`:

```
    // redirects any requests which have no logged in user
    if (is_null(Auth::id())) {
        return Redirect::route('login');
    }

    if (!$user->hasRole($role)) {
        return abort(403, 'Forbidden');
    }

    // otherwise process the request, all good - process the next request!
```

If you want to protect whole controllers with your role middleware, you can do that in your controller constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('role:administrator');
}
```

Or in the routes as IGP explained.

This will lock down your pages to ensure only the right people are accessing the pages, no GDPR fire alarms, all good! It is much safer than saying "*did the person type in the route in themselves*", because you are saying "*does this person have the right authorisation to access this page*".

Sorry that was a bit long, let me know any feedback you have.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace /test with your actual route:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
   return abort(404);
});
```